# Jquery .show() - Divs below the shown divs are not sliding down

Tags: jquery, css

I have 2 divs in my asp page

```
<div id="leftcolotherdestinations" style="display:none;">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlOtherDestinations" runat="server" CssClass="destinationpanel">
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
<div id="leftcolheaderupdates">
     Updates
</div>
```

**#leftcolotherdestinations** is shown with jquery when a button is clicked. It is ok so far. But when #leftcolotherdestinations is shown, **#leftcolheaderupdates** is sliding down but when the animation is finished it is going up where it was before. I want it to go down with the div above.
Here is my css;

```
#lefcoltotherdestinations
{
    margin-top:20px;
    display:block;
    height:20px;  
    background-color:#D8D2CE;
}
#leftcolheaderupdates
{
    display:block;
    height:20px;  
    background-color:#D8D2CE;
}
```

Comment: Can you show a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, of what you're working with?

Comment: You have a typo in your CSS: It has the selector `#lefcoltotherdestinations`, but your HTML has a div with the `id` `leftcolotherdestinations`. In the CSS, the `t` in `left` is misplaced (it's after `col`). With that fixed, it's fine: http://jsbin.com/imujuw I'd post this as an answer, but it doesn't account for the symptom you've described, so...

Comment: that's working, http://jsfiddle.net/ocanal/8qHc4/1/

Comment: Yes it is working but I can not see what the difference is with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved this problem by removing the floated elements (or making them "unfloated") inside the outer div. Thanks for comments.